# Centring video in viewport within a sticky footer layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm using Phillip Walton's 'solved-by-flexbox' sticky footer solution for my site. 
In addition to this, I have some video pages on which I want to centre the video embed (`video-container`) in the viewport (both horizontally and vertically)

Below is everything as it is set-up, and [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/k0zufff5/1/) a JSFiddle just for good measure.

```css
.Site {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  /* 1, 3 */
}
.Site-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  /* 2 */
  padding: var(--space) var(--space) 0;
  width: 100vw;
}
.Site-header,
.Site-footer {
  flex: none;
  /* 2 */
}
.Site-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 600;
  flex: none;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70vw;
  height: calc(70vw * 9 / 16);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <div class="Site-header">This is a header</div>
  <div class="Site-content">
    <div class="video-container">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/100978843" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Site-footer">This is the footer</div>
</body>
```

I've seen a few different options, but most of them rely on knowing the exact size of the div or object to be centred.

For example, this option:

```
.video-container
{
 width: 70vw;
 height: calc(70vw * 9 / 16);
 margin:0 auto;
 background:#f7f7f7;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
}
```

Doesn't work, my `video-container` element still sits at the top of the page.

I've seen another code example which uses Flexbox to centre:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
```

but this a no-go for me as it interferes with not only my sticky footer set-up but also the rest of the site content (for obvious reasons).

Is there another way to do this?

edit: I'm not sure why I'm receiving down votes. I've tried to explain the scenario with steps I have taken, and I've now provided full and complete code in both a JS Fiddle and a Stack Snippet. If there is anything else or my question is not clear then please, by all means let me know and I can edit the question.

Comment: Point being flexbox is not the answer here. If it's related to the viewport then it needs to be positioned and that will ignore any flexbox settings (and any elements around it probably).

Comment: @Paulie_D I think there's been some kind of misunderstanding here, I never claimed that flexbox was the answer at all. I just wanted to clarify, give some background and point out that was how I was constructing the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SO36651747

### Centring video in viewport within a sticky footer layout

Changed every style except the iframe. Got rid of the CSS variables (they had no ::root so they were useless). Made `.Site-content` a flex container because flex containers only affect their children. The elements you wanted to center were the grand-children of `.Site`, therefore it could not control the centering of the video-container.

Changed the style of the video container so that it's height and width maintains a 9:16 aspect ratio.

- See references below.
- Changes are marked with
- The red borders are there to show the distance between the header/footer/video.

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/drHx8uZTFWDp42x2i5Yx?p=preview)

[**README.md**](http://plnkr.co/edit/drHx8uZTFWDp42x2i5Yx?p=info)

```
.Site {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; 
  align-items: center; 
  align-content: center; 
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: column nowrap; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}

.Site-header,
.Site-footer {
  flex: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 600;
  height: 10vh; 
  width: 100vw; 
}

.Site-header {
  top: 0; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid red; 
}

.Site-footer {
  bottom: 0; 
  border-top: 1px solid red; 
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 0; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

**References:**

- [Flexbox - align-items](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/)
- [Responsive Video](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)